# Resizing Unity WebPlayer element when resizing browser

Tags: javascript, css, unity-game-engine, resize, unityscript

I'm trying to get a Unity WebPlayer control to resize when the browser is resized.  Here's the code I think is pertinent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function GetUnity() 
        {
            if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") 
            {
                return unityObject.getObjectById("unityPlayer");
            }
            return null;
        }

        function ResizeUnity()
        {
            //This function properly assigns innerWidth and Height to winWidth and winHeight
            GetWindowSize();

            var unity = GetUnity();
            if(unity != null)
            {
                //This does not properly resize anything at all
                unity.width = winWidth;
                unity.height = winHeight;
            }
        }
    }

    if (typeof unityObject != "undefined") 
    {
        GetWindowSize();
        //This replaces the unityPlayer div below with an actual WebPlayer object
        unityObject.embedUnity("unityPlayer", "WebPlayer.unity3d", winWidth, winHeight, params);            
    }
    -->
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    div#unityPlayer {
        cursor: default;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body margin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scroll="no" onResize="ResizeUnity()">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="unityPlayer">
                <div class="missing">
                    <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From various `alert()`s in the code, I can verify that `ResizeUnity()` is being called when I change the size of the window.  I can verify that `winWidth` and `winHeight` are getting proper values assigned to them upon resizing.  But, no matter what I do to the browser window, the Unity WebPlayer object stays the same size it was when it was loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `GetUnity()` function wasn't grabbing an element high enough up its `div` hierarchy for me to resize the correct element.  Updating my `ResizeUnity()` function with this did the trick:

```
function ResizeUnity()
{
    //This function properly assigns innerWidth and Height to winWidth and winHeight
    GetWindowSize();

    var unity = document.getElementById('unityPlayer');
    if(unity != null)
        {                   
            unity.style.width = winWidth + "px";
            unity.style.height = winHeight + "px";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the properties of the `div` that contains your game.
Most of the times CSS is enough to do that, you don't need JavaScript.

Here is a working example that displays a game using the browser's full width and height:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var u = new UnityObject2();
            jQuery(function() {
                u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "http://unity3d.com/files/live-demos/angrybots/AngryBots.unity3d");
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #unityPlayer {
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Some text that will be hidden...</p>
        <div id="unityPlayer"></div>
        <p>Some more text that will also be hidden.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```